# Strange "selector mangling" in Objective-C method with Boolean arguments

Tags: objective-c, macos, gcc, objective-c-runtime

I need to recover method names dynamically, via reflection calls at runtime. But get strange results for some.

My TestClass contains a method like:

```
- (void)testMethod6_NSRect:(NSRect)a1 int:(int)a2 int:(int)a3 bool:(Boolean)a4 {
    ...
}
```

When enumerating the above classes methods using class_copyMethodList() and fetching the method selectors via method_getName(), I get:

```
"testMethod6_NSRect:int:int:_Bool:"
```

Thus, the selector was rewritten somehow (by gcc?) to make "_Bool" from "bool". As far as I tested yet, this seems to be done only for a "bool" selector-part - if I change it to int:(int), as in:

```
- (void)testMethod1_int:(int)a1 int:(int)a2 int:(int)a3 int:(int)a4 {
    ...
}
```

I get the expected:

```
"testMethod1_int:int:int:int:"
```

Q:
Does anyone know the rules or a pointer to where I could find them for this "selector rewriting", or am I missing something? Is this only done for "bool"?
I also need to know if this behavior is depending on the gcc-version, osx-version or runtime library version.

I am using (gcc --version):
  i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
on a (uname -a) 
  10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0:

Comment: This is fascinating; I'm guessing that GCC is seeing `bool` and turning it into its underlying type name, not realizing it's part of a selector. Have you tried switching to the Clang compiler?

Comment: Try printing _cmd in the method.  Also, you should use llvm, if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in an ugly piece of preprocessor magic in the C99 standard header `<stdbool.h>`:

```
#define bool _Bool
```

C99 defines a type named `_Bool` which behaves like C++'s `bool` type. The define is there to be able to use it in C but with the C++ identifier.

Solution:

```
#undef bool
```

Comment: thanks - that is the problem; although I think it is a gcc bug to let selector-parts be translated via the preprocessor - as opposed to the whole selector...
But as I don't have control over the classes I load (binary), I may have to assume, that this happened to any compiled class out there already... (I wonder how many other such mis-translations have already found their way into binaries...)

Comment: This is a problem with all (conforming) implementations of cpp (the C preprocessor): The preprocessor simply does not understand the language. You can easily find other examples where it does not do what you would expect. So, no, it's not a bug but expected and relied upon behavior. Annoying, nevertheless.

Comment: What if you *intended* for the selector to be translated via a preprocessor directive? The pre-processor is what it is - a language unaware text processor. This isn't a bug, it's behaving as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BOOL instead of Boolean

Comment: same behavior. It seems to be a function of the selector, not the argument types. Also, as I do not have control over the code on which I need to reflect, I cannot prevent a method with such a name ever to be encountered (i.e. even if it did make a difference, it does not look like a generic solution to my problem) ...